# How do you get the Scala IDE presentation compiler to show you the log output of a compiler plugin?

Tags: eclipse, scala, compiler-construction

When I call the Scala compiler from the command line, using my own compiler plugin, I use the following two parameters to see what happens:

```
-Ylog:generatewrappers -Xprint:generatewrappers
```

This gives me all the information I need. Using the same plugin inside the Scala IDE for Eclipse, those options are not yet available in the compiler properties. If I just put them exactly as above in the "Additional command line parameters" field, it does not seem to have any effect, although I can see that the plugin is doing it's job.

So how can I get Eclipse to show me the output of the plugin/compiler, either in the Eclipse Console View or in the Problem View (or is there a special other View for this)?

EDIT: If anybody cares, I'm getting the very useful error message:

```
Error in Scala compiler: null
```

which is extremely frustrating. I tried using the -Ypresentation-log option, hoping to at least get the output in that file, but all it contains is something like this:

```
"wait for more work"(
  ),
"atnode"(
  1,
  1319373203925),
"asked"(
  ),
"atnode"(
  2,
  1319373203926),
...
"exception thrown"(
  "scala.tools.nsc.interactive.ShutdownReq$"(
    ))
```

This error does not come when I compile from the command line using the same options, so I have no way of debugging it without the actual presentation compiler output.

Comment: The presentation compiler logs stuff to the problem view, but at level Info. Are you sure that you're showing all the items  in your problems view? Show->Show All? I don't remember whether the log messages from compiler plugins show up there, but the compiler messages definitely do, if you have -Ypresentation-debug or -Ypresentation-verbose checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All compiler log messages are printlns. They go to stdout. Run Eclipse from the command prompt to see them.

Comment: Haven't tried it but that sound reasonable, so you get the points.